# moverme en un textbox fila por fila

Tags: vba

estoy haciendo un programa basico en visual basic, lo que hace es que el usuario introduce un txt con varias cadenas y estas se visualizan en un textbox así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que necesito es recorrer el textbox fila por fila de tal forma que pueda extraer cada caracter de cada cadena, intenté de esta forma pero creo que no es correcta?Acá les dejo el ciclo que intenté utilizar

```
For Each linea As String In txtb_tarch.Lines

Next
```

Comment: El contenido de ese textbox irá separado por un espacio o un retorno de carro, no? Lo que tienes que hacer es trocear con Split utilizando el separador que corresponda.

De todas formas tu código está incompleto ¿qué vas a hacer dentro de ese For Each?

Tienes que proporcionar un ejemplo más claro y mejor informado.

Answer (score -1):

Entiendo que necesitas algo así:

```
Sub lineasTB()
Dim linea() As String
linea = Split(TextBox1.Text, vbCrLf)

Dim s
For Each s In linea
'aquí va tu código
    MsgBox (s)

Next s
End Sub
```

Espero sea de utilidad
Saludos

Comment: El código sólo no sirve, tiene que ir con una explicación.